# Link errors, unresolved symbols QString, QComboBox, QSlider, QAbstractButton, QRadioButton,

Tags: c++, c, qt, linker, qt5

while compiling a small Qt test application I stumble about a few hundred unsresolved symbols as mentioned in sbuject. This seems to be caused by a .lib I forgot to link against (Qt5GuiD.lib and Qt5Cored.lib are already there).

So which .lib's do I have to add to my project settings in order to resolve these dependencies?

Thanks!

Comment: QComboBox, QSlider, QAbstractButton, QRadioButton are all QWidgets so you seem to forgot linking `Qt5WidgetsD.lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `Qt5Widgetsd.lib` or `Qt5Widgets.lib` for release. When I release an app I always have `Qt5Core.dll` , `Qt5Gui.dll` and `Qt5Widgets.dll` to deploy.

The lib should be somewhere in `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\lib` for example on a standard install.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the docs for all Qt classes that you have used and look which libraries they belong to. The bare minimum for a window application is `QtCore`, `QtGui` and `QtWidgets`.